# Media library only shows for admin. Doesn't show editor or below

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

There is no problem of viewing the media as an administrator.

But when we login as an editor any other lower roles the media library does not load the content (see screenshot).

It does work on this page if I change the view to list view. But isn't available when I try to select media inside a post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: What we currently see as an editor]

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with thumbnails or so. Have you tried regenerating them?